# Jquery: Append/Remove items on hidden field on click

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a program that allows you to record absence when a grid is clicked 1 time. When you click it the second time, it will record the grid as late. When you click it for the third time, the status will revert to the original. I am able to append absences to a hidden field to be posted on another php. However, I can't seem to append the late records to another hidden field. When I look at my other php file, the absence is still recorded even if it should have been removed from the list. Worst part is, nothing is being appended to the late hidden field.

I badly need help with this. Also, I hope you could explain where I made a fault so I could understand the code. Thanks!

Here's the code: http://jsfiddle.net/Ms6FP/2/

Comment: create a demo in jsfiddle.net

Comment: A bit new to Jquery, so I'll ask this. Why have the following line of code? $("#sortable li").each( . The reason I ask is that shouldn't ids be unique? I couldn't find the sortable li element when I looked through the code.

Comment: Here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ms6FP/1/

Comment: @AmitBhargava the the sortable li element refers to the li within the ul which has an id of "sortable". So basically, "sortable li" means "the li within the element with the id, sortable"

Comment: Thanks! Knew I was missing something!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way to do this would be to create the contents of the hidden fields on submit.

Assuming your submit button is given the id mySubmitButton and you have a hidden field with an id lateHiddenField, you can do something like:

```
$("#mySubmitButton").submit(function(){
  $(".late").each(function(index,value){  //iterate through each late student
    //append the late student's name
    $("#lateHiddenField").text($("#lateHiddenField").text()+value.text()+"\n");
  })

  //do the same for the absent students
}
```

The advantages are:

- Faster processing- this only runs once
- Simpler code- you don't have
  to revise anything

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are trying to give out the total number of students who are late through different state of clicks.

On that case [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/Ms6FP/3/) is an working solution

Slight change to markup, to make it more manipulative

```
<div id="collect1">
    late: <span>0</span>
</div>
```

Then, count the length of your already maintained array and update

```
$("#collect1").children("span").html(late.length);
```